# ¿Cómo puedo cargar una imagen a SQLite en android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, hardware

La imagen puede cargarse desde la galería, o bien, tomarla directamente.
En ambos casos, en una variable global estoy almacenando la Uri de cada foto... pero no sé sí pueda cargarse dicha imagen a la base de datos a partir de la Uri.

```
    public void guardaDatos(){
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy");


    conn = new SQLiteHelper(this, "bd_App",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            ""+Tablas.TABLA_PUNTO_VENTA+"("+Tablas.NOMBRE_PUNTO+","+Tablas.NOMBRE_LIDER_TURNO+","+Tablas.FOTO_PUNTO_VENTA+","+Tablas.FECHA+") " +
            "VALUES ( '"+etRestaurante.getText().toString()+"'," +
            "'"+etLiderTurno.getText().toString()+"'," +
            ""+readFile(imageUri.toString())+"," +
            ""+simpleDateFormat.toString()+")");
    db.close();
}
```

Intenté guardar la foto de esta manera, pero no ha salido muy bien...

```
private byte[] readFile(String file) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(file);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int len; (len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, (e.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, (e2.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return bos != null ? bos.toByteArray() : null;
}
```

Y esta es la función que usaba a la hora de intentar cargar la foto. La había visto en otra pregunta del sitio

```
Uri imageUri;
Bitmap thumbnail;
private static final int PICTURE_RESULT = 122 ;
private SQLiteHelper conn;
private boolean rutaGaleria;
private ImageView imagen;
private EditText etLiderTurno,etRestaurante;
String imageUrl;
```

Estas son las variables que estoy usando en el código

Comment: Hola Juan es importante revises [ask], varias de tus preguntas no obtuvieron respuesta anteriormente porque no fueron correctamente planteadas, agrega lo que has realizado o investigado, saludos.ç

Comment: Agradezco la observación, aún soy nuevo en este sitio, como puedes ver...